# awk read float precision: cannot read small floats, e.g. 4e-320

Tags: bash, awk, floating-point, floating-point-precision, gawk

I cannot get `awk` or `gawk` to read small floats in scientific notation and interpret them correctly as floating point numbers.

I just want to output numbers above a small threshold with awk.

**Example**:

consider the following input:

```
4
3e-20
4.5e-320
3
1e-10
```

I want to threshold by 1e-15, so i do the following:

```
echo -e "4\n3e-20\n4.5e-320\n3\n1e-10"  |  awk '$1 > 1e-15'
```

which gives output:

```
4
4.5e-320
3
1e-10
```

Of course, 4.5e-320 does not pass the 1e-15 threshold, but `awk` and `gawk` fail to reject it!

I looked up `(g)awk` floating point precision.  It seems to apply *only* to arithmetic operations *within* awk.

So, replacing   `awk '$1 > 1e-15'`  with   `gawk -v PREC="double" '$1 > 1e-15'`  also fails.  It also fails with `PREC="quad"`

thus, I conclude that `(g)awk` is not *reading* 4.5e-320 as a float, but instead a string?

Comment: I get `4, 3, 1e-10` as output from your command here. What version of awk are you using? What locale? Does using `$1+0 > 1e-15` work better?

Comment: 64 bit floating points have usually range between e-308 to e308

Comment: @karakfa  it fails using "quad" as well.  question edited to show this

Comment: @EtanReisner  i am using  `GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1`

Comment: @EtanReisner   the `$1+0` trick worked.  why is that? maybe you can submit is as an answer.  Also, what locale should i use in awk?  im not familiar with locales at all

Comment: Uses `+0` forces awk to convert the argument to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the expected output from awk version 3.1.5.

I get your output from awk version 3.1.7.

You can force awk to convert a string to a number by adding zero to it.

So try this awk script instead:

```
printf '4\n3e-20\n4.5e-320\n3\n1e-10\n' | awk '$1+0 > 1e-15'
```

Comment: so awk version 3.1.7 lost functionality?

Comment: It certainly changed from 3.1.5 (I've seen this a bunch now). I can't say specifically what the change was that was involved her though.

Answer (score 1):

one can further simply that to just :

```
  printf '4\n3e-20\n4.5e-320\n3\n1e-10\n'
```

> ```
> awk '1e-15 < +$_'     # mawk or gawk
>                    or
> awk '1e-15 < +$+_'    # nawk
> ```

```
4
3
1e-10
```

another approach is to multiply the inverse of it -

- `awk`s that can't normally handle `big-int`s and `big-float`s can properly handle the filter
- it modifies the filter from one that discards all negative values to one that simply filters by the magnitude of the number, skipping the extra step of having to obtain the absolute value first :

  ```
  printf '12345e+76543\n-996633e+224466\n6543e-4567\n4'
         '\n3e-20\n4.5e-320\n-248163264\n3\n1e-10\n'     |
  ```

> ```
> mawk '$++NF = int(1e15 * $_) ? "pass-filter" : "-"' OFS='\r\t\t\t'
> ```

```
12345e+76543        pass-filter
-996633e+224466     pass-filter
6543e-4567          -
4                   pass-filter
3e-20               -
4.5e-320            -
-248163264          pass-filter
3                   pass-filter
1e-10               pass-filter
```