# Regex that extracts everything until finds "/", starting from the end

Tags: regex, grep

I'm writing a script in bash where I use the `grep` function with a regex expression to extract an id which I will be using as a variable.

The goal is to extract all characters until it finds `/`, but the caracter `'` and `}` should be ignored.

file.txt:

```
{'name': 'projects/data/locations/us-central1/datasets/dataset/source1/messages/B0g2_e8gG_xaZzpbliWvjlShnVdRNEw='}
```

command:

```
cat file.txt | grep -oP "[/]+^"
```

The current command isn't working.

desired output:

```
B0g2_e8gG_xaZzpbliWvjlShnVdRNEw=
```

Comment: This is very classically the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) (example 1).

Comment: Hi @jhnc, I updated the question with expected output

Comment: So you want to ignore `}` as well ?

Comment: yes, you're right. I didn't realized about `}`

Comment: `"[^/]+(?='})"` or `"(?<=/)[^/]+(?=')"`

Comment: it worked! thanks @jhnc
would you post it, I will mark as the answer
or give some detail on what each expression is doing and I can add as answer here

thanks a lot

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you gave was: `[/]+^`

It has a few mistakes:

- Your use of `^` at the end seems to imply you think you can ask the software to search backwards - You can't;
- `[/]` matches **only** the slash character.

Your sample shows what appears to be a malformed JSON object containing a key-value pair, each enclosed in single-quotes. JSON requires double-quotes so perhaps it is not JSON.

If several assumptions are made, it is possible to extract the section of the input that you seem to want:

- file contains a single line; and
- key and value are strings surrounded by single-quote; and
- either:

  - the value part is immediately followed by `}`; or
  - the name part cannot contain `/`

You are using `-P` option to grep, so lookaround operators are available.

```
(?<=/)[^/]+(?=')
```

- lookbehind declares match is preceded by `/`
- one or more non-slash (the match)
- lookahead declares match is followed by `'`

```
[^/]+(?='})
```

- one or more non-slash (the match)
- lookahead declares match is followed by `'` then `}`

Note that the match begins as early in the line as possible and with greedy `+` it is as long as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F"[/']" '{print $(NF-1)}' file.txt
B0g2_e8gG_xaZzpbliWvjlShnVdRNEw=
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic [parameter parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
$: x="$(<file.txt)"            # file contents in x
$: x="${x##*/}"                # strip to last / to get rid of 'name'
$: x="${x//[^[:alnum:]=]}"     # strip not alphanumeric or = to clean the end
$: echo "$x"
B0g2e8gGxaZzpbliWvjlShnVdRNEw=
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data structure is always like that and you can use `jq`, translate the single quotes to double quotes, take the name property and then the last values after splitting on `/`

```
tr "'" '"' < file | jq -r '.name | split("/") | last'
```

Output

```
B0g2_e8gG_xaZzpbliWvjlShnVdRNEw=
```

Answer (score 1):

With `jq` you could try following code. Firstly change all occurrences of `'` to `"` in json to make it valid one by using `tr` command(as per your shown samples), then we can use `jq` command's `sub` function to get the required output.

```bash
jq -r '.[] | sub(".*/";"")' <(tr "'" '"' < Input_file)
```

***OR*** you want to look for specifically name element then try following:

```bash
 jq -r '.name | sub(".*/";"")' <(tr "'" '"' < Input_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "${inputdata}"|
```

> ```
> mawk ++NF OFS= FS='^.+/|[}\47]+$'
> ```

```
B0g2_e8gG_xaZzpbliWvjlShnVdRNEw=
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: @Chris : like u said - learning - learning is a 2-way street that requires both sides to be active participants of the conversation instead of being a 1-way street. My answer is very much the same approach as the other ones, in a more simplified manner. Funny you didn't criticize Ed Morton's solution that also came with zero amount of explanation.

Comment: This answer was in the "low quality answers" review queue, which is where I saw it. I stand by my comment: it isn't very clear, and it could benefit from some explanation. Your misuse of Markdown is also confusing. What's with the blockquote? Note that at least one other user agrees with me, based on my upvoted comment. I suggest you take feedback with an open mind instead of being defensive.

Comment: @Chris : and have you actually thought about why Stack Network sites have an unfortunate propensity of attracting leeches the way lampposts attract moths?

Comment: I don't understand why you're being so hostile. [You](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73357622/354577) [clearly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73347796/354577) [know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73344475/354577) [how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73344397/354577) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73327093/354577) [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73319722/354577) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73318420/354577). I'm just asking you to do the same here. Again, this answer is in the "low quality answers" queue. I'm just trying to help.

Comment: @Chris : if u think it's low quality then so be it.